# Is there a way to use two series (or some kind of group) in highcharter wordcloud?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a wordcloud with Highcharter R package (based on Highcharts library) to show two categories of sentiments (positive and negative) in just one wordcloud.

The point is that I want to show a legend too. My problem is that when I got to show the legend, then the words are not being aligned. And when I got to show the data in the right way, then I could not show the legend.

The simplest case showing my issue is the one that follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

positive <-
  c(
    "tranquilo",
    "tranquila",
    "nova"  ,
    "burocratico" ,
    "bom"      ,
    "assertivo"   ,
    "rapido"    ,
    "transparente"
  )

negative <-
  c(
    "trabalhoso" ,
    "conduzida" ,
    "passa"  ,
    "congelada" ,
    "pessima"  ,
    "moroso"   ,
    "pouco",
    "opinar"  ,
    "passado"  ,
    "afastado"
  )

df <- list(
  tibble("term" = positive,
         "sentiment" = "positive"),
  tibble("term" = negative,
         "sentiment" = "negative")
) %>% bind_rows()

df %>%
  hchart(
    "wordcloud",
    hcaes(name = "term", group = "sentiment"),
    showInLegend = TRUE,
    colorByPoint = FALSE
  ) %>%
  hc_colors(c("#E0362C", "#189D3E"))
```

The result is:

[image]

If I change "group" parameter by "color" `hcaes(name = "term", color = "sentiment")`, then what I get is:
[image]

Thanks in advance.
Wlademir.

PS: I think that a solution in JS could also help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to position words in 2 separate series. You can use one wordcloud series where every point has defined `seriesId` index. Now, you can use another 2 fake line series (they cannot be the wordcloud type) and you can write a custom `legendItemClick` event logic on them. Whenever the user clicks on the legend item, the algorithm loops through all words and "hides" the proper ones.

You can take a look at this example here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7tq01sn5/

Let me know what do you think and if this solution suits you. When rewriting to R, you can use JS("") function to convert your JavaScript function code to R.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this as I had the same issue.

Could be an issue with highcharter, although was resolved with:

```
hcaes(name = "term", color = "sentiment")
```

i.e. 'color' and not 'colour'